# What is the name of the movie where a guy gets a bullet to the head, and survives because of a gel like gauze?

Tags: story-identification, movie

Does anyone know the name of the movie where a guy gets shot in the face, but his friend immediately puts a weird gauze-like gel on that stops the bullet from going any further? The gel wraps around the wound and stops the damage.

Comment: Please go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and answer as many of those questions as you can, editing them into your question. It will help us help you.

Comment: Under easy questions, when did you see it? In what country? What language? Live action or animated? In theaters? On TV? Online? Did it seem like it was originally made in a different language? Do you remember why the guy got shot in the face, or by what sort of weapon? Do you remember if the gel was magic or science? Do you remember anything else that happened?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Could it be *[Kingsman: The Golden Circle](https://www.inverse.com/article/36583-kingsman-golden-circle-foam-wound)*?

> Audiences believed Hart was a goner at the end of *Kingsman: The Secret Service*, but a flashback sequence in *The Golden Circle* reveals that two members of the U.S.-run Statesman agency swarmed onto the crime to investigate after Hart was left for dead. The American spies, played by Channing Tatum and Halle Berry, go into first-aid mode by wrapping a plastic-like shrink-wrap around Hart’s injured head.

> When it’s activated, the shrink-wrap rapidly inflates with a swirl of orange and blue gel, which then fills in the hole in his skull. This “bio-foam” is what keeps [the victim] alive until nanites (nano-scale robots) rush in to repair the damage. It may seem like another ridiculous made-up tool in the super-spy toolkit, but its premise is something actual scientists have already considered.

It contains a scene very much like the one you suggest (twice, actually). I came upon it by doing a Google search for `film gel cures gunshot wound`.

Comment: Kingsman it is !! Thanks a lot

Comment: Huh, I don't usually see "identify" requests for such recent movies. It was released on DVD a little over a month ago.

Comment: Please add a spoiler alert! Too late for me... :-(

Comment: @Offirmo: Oof... that would involve most of the answer, since it's largely quotes.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds sort of like [Kingsmen: the golden circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingsman:_The_Golden_Circle), in it there's a gel like substance which gets wrapped around a characters head in order to save them from a headshot.

Comment: Omg yes this is it ! It's right when harry gets shot in the front of the church ! Thank you so much